# How to configure jackson-modules-java8 in Ktor

Tags: jackson, ktor, jsr310

I am trying to configure `jackson-modules-java8` with Ktor and Jackson but to no avail.

The module is added to `gradle.build`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.0-rc2'
    ...
}
```

According to the Jackson docs I should do this:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
    .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
    .build();
```

But in Ktor I can only do this:

```kotlin
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    jackson {
        // `this` is the ObjectMapper
        this.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        // what to do here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According with the [official example](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/blob/1.3.0/feature/jackson/src/JacksonApplication.kt) if you want to add a module you could use

`registerModule`

as this:

```kotlin
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    jackson {
        configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true)
        setDefaultPrettyPrinter(DefaultPrettyPrinter().apply {
            indentArraysWith(DefaultPrettyPrinter.FixedSpaceIndenter.instance)
            indentObjectsWith(DefaultIndenter("  ", "\n"))
        })
        registerModule(JavaTimeModule())  // support java.time.* types
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great. I also had to disable a feature to get the result I wanted, but now it works: 
`disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)`